# binomial theorem problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm not sure how to do this:

show that $(x + 12y)^{13}\equiv x^{13}  - y^{13} {\mod 13}$ for all integers

It's part of a question on the binomial theorem, but that's all I've got.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: $(x + 12y)^{13}\equiv (x - y)^{13} {\mod 13}$

Hint 2: in the expansion of $(a + b)^{p}$ for $p$ prime, each term has a co-efficient which is a multiple of $p$ except the first and last.

Comment: Why is hint 1 true? And how do I know 2? And how do I use these facts?

Comment: I don't know what you know.  Hint 1 is true because $13y \equiv 0 {\mod 13}$ and because $(a+b c)^d \equiv a^d {\mod b}$.  You use these facts by letting $a=x$, $b=-y$ and $p=13$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

If we apply [freshman dream theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic) we can write :

$(x+12y)^{13} \equiv x^{13}+(12y)^{13} \pmod {13}$

Now , use a fact :

$12 \equiv -1 \pmod {13} \Rightarrow 12^{13} \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$